# How to retrieve the schema (type and columns) from a sql table and enforce them on a table in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, schema

I have multiple tables inside a sql database. Of each of them I want to have the column names and types in Azure Data Factory.

In Adf I have multiple tables that need to be copied to (already created)tables with the same name in the sql database. The tables (files) in adf have more columns and also different types than the tables in the sql database. Now if I try to send the data from adf to the sql database table, adf will throw an error saying that the types and columns don't add up. Therefore I want to enforce the schema of the sql table on the corresponding table in adf. (Different schema for a different table).

How can I do this?

Comment: can you add images of pipeline and what is source and sink?

Comment: What does **tables in adf** mean? Could you explain more in detail? Are you storing data in ADLS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach which involves two level pipelines.

But note that, **this approach only works when the source and sink table names are same and existing column names from both are same**.

Here, for sample I took the ADLS csv files as source with same names as tables names with `.csv`.

First, in the parent pipeline, get the list of table names from your target database with below query using lookup activity (uncheck firstRow).

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables;
```

Give the lookup activity output array `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` to a ForEach activity.

Inside ForEach, first we need to get the structure of the target table. For that use the **Get meta data activity with parameterized SQL database dataset**. Give the `@item().name` as table name and select `Structure` in it.

[image]

Now, this will give the structure of the table. To copy the multiple tables without the Column not found errors, first we need to **build a dynamic schema and give that in the copy activity mapping**.

To build that schema for every table, use the **child pipeline**. In child pipeline, create an array parameter and pass the above Get meta data structure array to the child pipeline.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure
```

[image]

In the Child pipeline, first create 3 variables like below.

[image]

In first set variable activity, select `schema` variable and give this string.

```
{"type": "TabularTranslator","mappings":
```

Now, we need to build the **mapping array**. To do that, use a **ForEach** activity give the `@pipeline().parameters.sqlstructures` parameter to it and make sure to check on **Sequential** here.

Inside this ForEach, take an **append variable activity** and give below expression for the `mapping` array.

```
@json(concat('{"source": {"name":"',item().name,'","type": "String"},"sink": {"name": "',item().name,'","type": "',item().logicalType,'"}}'))
```

[image]

After ForEach, take another set variable activity for the variable `final_schema` and give the below expression.

```
@concat(variables('schema'),string(variables('mapping')),',"typeConversion": true,"typeConversionSettings":{"allowDataTruncation": false,"treatBooleanAsNumber": false}}')
```

[image]

The mapping will be generated in a string like this for sample.

[image]

Now, return this string to the parent pipeline like below.

[image]

In the parent pipeline, take a copy activity, give your source and sink (Use dataset parameter for the table names and give the current table `@item().name` in it).

Click on the dynamic content in the mapping and give the below expression using the returned variable.

```
@json(activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.Mapping_schema)
```

[image]

Debug the pipeline and whatever might be the extra columns in your source tables, those will be ignored and only the required columns data will be copied in to the target tables.

**My result:**

[image]

[image]

**My parent pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Parent",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tablename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "columnCount",
                                    "structure"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "Child_pipeline",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sqlstructures": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy from source to target",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "value": "@json(activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.Mapping_schema)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SampleSource",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tablename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT name FROM sys.tables;",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "tablename": "sample1"
                        }
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Child pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Child_pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "start schema",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sqlstructures",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "mapping",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{\"source\": {\"name\":\"',item().name,'\",\"type\": \"String\"},\"sink\": {\"name\": \"',item().name,'\",\"type\": \"',item().logicalType,'\"}}'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "start schema",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "schema",
                    "value": "{\"type\": \"TabularTranslator\",\"mappings\":"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Build final schema",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final_schema",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@concat(variables('schema'),string(variables('mapping')),',\"typeConversion\": true,\"typeConversionSettings\":{\"allowDataTruncation\": false,\"treatBooleanAsNumber\": false}}')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Return Final schema to parent",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Build final schema",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "Mapping_schema",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@variables('final_schema')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "sqlstructures": {
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "schema": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "final_schema": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "mapping": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```